# state value null in initialFiles react dropzone

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, dropzone.js, react-dropzone

i have problem with render state in reactjs,
when i call state on dropzone the state value is null,
I define the state in the cunstructor with the default value array [ ], why does that happen, even though the other states are not null when rendered

```
import React from "react";
import { DropzoneArea } from 'material-ui-dropzone';
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

class BranchProvider extends React.Component {


}
export default withRouter(BranchProvider);
```

can colleagues help me in solving this problem
my problem with initialFiles, state data can't be read here

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.getDataBrnachProvider();
  this.state = {
    result: {},
    formValue: {},
    valBranch: "",
    valAddress: "",
    fileLocation: [],
  }
}

getDataBrnachProvider() {
    let idBranch = this.props.match.params.eventId;
    fetch(this.api + "/branch-provider/" + idBranch, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      }
    }).then(res => res.json()).then((result) => {
      if(result.code === 200){
        this.setState({
          result: result.data,
          valBranch: result.data.branch_name,
          valAddress: result.data.branch_address,
        })
        const file = [];
        result.data.branch_location_photo.forEach((item) => {
        file.push(this.apiBase+item)
        });

        this.setState({
        fileLocation: file
        })
      }
    }, (error) => {
      console.log(error)
    })
  }

render() {
    return (
      <>
      <Col md="12">
        <FormGroup>
            <label
            className="form-control-label"
            htmlFor="AddLocationPhoto"
            >
            Location Photo
            <small> max. 3 files with 2 MB of maximum file size for each file(s) (file extentions: *jpg, *png, *jpeg, *gif) </small>
            </label>
            <DropzoneArea
                acceptedFiles={['image/*']}
                dropzoneText={"Drag and drop an image here or click"}
                onChange={(files) => {
                console.log('Files:', files)
                this.handleChange(files, "branch_location_photo")
                }
                }
                maxFileSize={5000000}
                filesLimit={3}
                showPreviewsInDropzone={false}
                showPreviews={true}
                initialFiles = { 
                    this.state.fileLocation && this.state.fileLocation ? this.state.fileLocation : []
                }
                
            />
            </FormGroup>
        </Col>
      </>
    );
}
```

when, I do console.log(this.state.fileLocation). the result i got is an empty array ( [ ] ) then after a few seconds, it will display the data

[image]

Comment: Where are your seeing `null`? inside `onChange` method?

Comment: yes, but I want to display the image in the state fileLocation and preview the image, but the value is null

Comment: when, I do console.log(this.state.fileLocation). the result i got is an empty array ( [ ] ) then after a few seconds, it will display the data

Comment: It can be because `fileLocation` doesn't update correctly. Can you try logging out where you are updating file

Comment: Ahh it may be happening because of you are hitting api. Try adding condition in your render `this.state.fileLocation.length===0 return null` otherwise run your code

Comment: where do i put the code, in initialFiles dropzone?

Comment: Inside render method of your component

Comment: is there a way to retrieve this.state.fileLocation after the data is filled in from the API or this.state.fileLocation won't render with an empty array before the data is filled?